# Ruby doesn't read carriage return (\r) in output?

Tags: ruby, output

in ruby, how do I make my output (via puts method) on one line, as opposed to line after line, and my console being flooded with output.  Basically I want the output to continuously update on one line, and keep writing over the last output.  I tried doing a '\r' character at the end of the string, but ruby just ignores it and keeps printing the output of my while loop line after line:

```
i=0
  while i<90
    puts  "#{i} matt lao \r"
    i+=1
  end
```

I just want one continuously updated line.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`puts` will always print a new line at the end, so it's doing your carriage return but then a new line after that.  Use `print` instead.

```
90.times { |i| print "#{i} matt lao \r" }
```

To see it's actually doing the right thing, you can stick in a `sleep`:

```
90.times { |i| print "#{i} matt lao \r"; sleep 0.01 }
```

Comment: but what if i have a nested pair of while loops  and i need to print out output within both the loops,  so far puts is the only way i've found to print out output that isn't the last line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `print` instead of `puts`.

For example:

```
90.times do |i|
  print "#{i} matt lao \r"; sleep 0.02
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use print without any carriage return which will work just fine.

like this

```
 2.1.1 :016 > 0.upto(4){|i| print "#{i} "}
 0 1 2 3 4  => 0
```

`puts` automatically appends a new line whereas `print` doesn't.